# find all combination without overlapping

Tags: permutations, combinations

(*Constraint) Kinds of number should be limited in 3

(ex. {1,1,1,1} o/ {1,2,3} o / {1,1,2,2,5,5,4} x)

And I want to find series of Integer.

For example, if n = 4 (n is length of numbers) 
{2, 7, 2, 7}

the whole combinations of these numbers are..

2, 7, 2, 7

2, 2, 7, 7

7, 2, 2, 7

7, 7, 2, 2

2, 7, 7, 2

7, 2, 7, 2

six.

It might easy if n is small number, but the more **n** grows up, the more complexity going bigger,, !

For instance, {1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,6,6,6,6,6,6,6}

In this case, how can i calculate all of combination?

Comment: hint:  if you treated all the numbers as different, there'd be $n!$.  Now if you have, say, $k_1$ of the first type you must divide by $k_1!$ because permutations of those don't matter.  Carry on this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you are asking how to count how many ordered partitions of fixed sizes exist.  Worded a different way, it sounds as if you are asking in how many ways you can arrange all entries of a multiset with possible repitition.

Here I use the following notation for a multiset: $\{n_a\cdot A, n_b\cdot B,n_c\cdot C\}$ is a multiset with $n_a$ copies of $A$, $n_b$ copies of $B$, et cetera.  For example, $\{1\cdot M, 4\cdot I, 4\cdot S, 2\cdot P\} = \{M,I,I,I,I,S,S,S,S,P,P\}$

> The number of arrangements of all entries of a multiset $\{n_a\cdot A,n_b\cdot B,\dots, n_k\cdot K\}$ where $n_a+n_b+\dots+n_k=N$ is given by the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem): $$\binom{N}{n_a,n_b,\dots,n_k}=\frac{N!}{n_a!n_b!\cdots n_k!}$$

This can be proven in the following way using binomial coefficients and multiplication principle:

- Step 1: Pick which locations are occupied by the A's
- Step 2: Pick which remaining locations are occupied by the B's
- $\vdots$

You will find the expression simplifies to that given above.

For example, the quintessential problem is "How many arrangements of the word `MISSISSIPPI` exist?"

In other words, how many ways can you arrange all elements of the multiset $\{1\cdot M, 4\cdot I, 4\cdot S, 2\cdot P\}$?

The answer being: $\frac{11!}{1!4!4!2!} = 34650$